# How to publish my app on new Expo version for testing users?

Tags: react-native, expo

I remember that I used to publish my apps on expo accounts using the MetroBundler page generated by the cli. After that I was able to scan the QR without being in the same wifi and test my app in a real device in any part of the world, But it seems now the metrobundler page is not longer active. I Know that in EXPO new version there is a EAS BUILD which I used but it is just generating the bundle and if you want to test you have to download the app and load into the simulator which is hard to my clients to do.

Here is the **old** MetroBundler interface:

[image: Old metro bundler]

Does anyone know if this publish option was deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

`expo publish` is the anwser. At the end of the build phase you will see a link that you can go and scan the QR. However at this time there is some issues about routing.